# Maven project as a dependency module of gradle project

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies

Now I have a gradle project called "Gradle_Project",and another maven project called "Maven_Project".The gradle project depends on the maven project.

In the build.gradle file of  Gradle_Project:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.uwantsoft', name: 'maven_project', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'  
}
```

In the pom.xml of Maven_Project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.uwantsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven_project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Does it mean I have to publish the maven project to my local maven center manually?
Is it possible to do something like project dependency in the build.gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile module(":Maven_Project")
}
```

And do not need to publish it manually to the maven local center when upgrading on the maven project every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gradle and Maven are not compatible in regards to project dependencies. You will need to publish the artifact to a repository with Maven. Only then you can consume the artifact with the appropriate coordinates from Gradle.